# Is the derivation of this formula acceptable?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2=\frac{n(2n+1)(n+1)}{6}$

Derivation:

$\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{i=k}^{n}i$

I thought of this form by drawing out the first few squares as geometrical figures made by dots, each one representing a unit area. The lengths of each line going through the dots can be found by a series of summations where one term is removed in each successive summation hence the above equation.

We can easily show that

$\sum_{i=k}^{n}i=k(n-k+1)+\frac{(n-k)(n-k+1)}{2}$

The summation then becomes

$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k(n-k+1)+\frac{(n-k)(n-k+1)}{2}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2$

letting

$\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2=c$,$\sum_{i=1}^{n}i=u$, and "distributing" the summation, we then get

$nu-c+u+\frac{1}{2}(n^3-2nu+n^2-u+c)=c$

here we have a $2c$ term on one side and a $\frac{1}{2}c$ term on the other so they won't cancel and we can, therefore, solve for c. solving for c we get

$\frac{u+n^2(n+1)}{3}=c$

using the formula for the summation of the first n integers and substituting in for $u$ we have

$\frac{n(n+1)+2n^2(n+1)}{6}=c$

factoring out a $n+1$, and then a $n$, we get

$\frac{n(2n+1)(n+1)}{6}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2$

which is what we sought to show.

Q.E.D

The only question I have is if this derivation is considered acceptable? I don't see it used and I highly doubt that I would be the first to try looking at this problem geometrically. It also feels a bit more intuitive to me.